# The body of my website is sitting about 20px Higher than the bottom of the screen

Tags: html

If you goto [blgz.co](http://www.blgz.co/user/register) you will notice that the Body is floating about 20px higher than the bottom of the page. I have no padding set anywhere that would be effecting this. Any help would be great! Thanks Guys!!

Comment: This question is useless for any future visitors once you've fixed your site.

Comment: That's great. But the whole point of this site is to help the person asking the question. AKA me. If it's useless why even bother opening up the thread and wasting my time and yours. Probably because you got nothing better to do but troll.

Comment: @George Right. However, the current question format is still not good. You should create a standalone, minimal showcase which exhibits the problem, and post this here. That way, you make the question easier answerable, you do your homework (that’s not our job!) and you have created a valuable question whose answers can help other people.

Comment: I have seen you alredy solved it while I was working on it. I was going to suggest searching your css files for the color #121212 wich was unique for that piece at the bottom of the page

Comment: Hmmm I don't understand what you mean by a standalone, minimal showcase which exhibits the problem. I'm running off a drupal core so idk how easy it would be to try and shrink the problem if I don't know what it is! But I will try next time. =)

Comment: @George: If you post code exhibiting the problem, and someone else posts an answer, it is useful for later visitors.  The whole point of this site is to provide an ongoing repository of solutions to problems, and not to fix individual problems with lost context.  I have been posting answers to problems for a couple years, and am very definitely *not* a troll.  However, it sounds from the discussion like you're learning, so I'll retract my downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add *zero* `font-size` and `line-height` to your `.clearfix:after` pseudoclass:

```
.clearfix:after {
  /* magic here */
  font-size:   0;
  line-height: 0;
  /* /magic here */

  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work =/ It caused all my fonts to drop to 0px

Comment: You've apparently missed `:after`. It _does_ work. Tested on your exact site with user stylesheet.

Comment: oh woops you're right!!! Didn't notice you posted the after part =)